# accessing elements of json in terminal

Tags: json, terminal

I have a number of large json files that I need to be able to read quickly in the terminal.  I am interested accessing attributes in the last element of each json, which, for example, might look like this:

```
        },
        "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/android\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for Android</a>",
        "text": "RT @kosaqsi_tweets: Ah ah..!!!",
        "truncated": false,
        "user": {
            "contributors_enabled": false,
            "created_at": "Tue May 06 04:48:07 +0000 2014",
            "default_profile": true,
            "default_profile_image": false,
            "description": "",
            "entities": {
                "description": {
                    "urls": []
                }
            },
            "favourites_count": 2147,
            "follow_request_sent": false,
            "followers_count": 72,
            "following": false,
            "friends_count": 207,
            "geo_enabled": true,
            "has_extended_profile": false,
            "id": 2479274491,
            "id_str": "2479274491",
            "is_translation_enabled": false,
            "is_translator": false,
            "lang": "en",
            "listed_count": 1,
            "location": "Singapore",
            "name": "karthikeyan vedalam",
            "notifications": false,
            "profile_background_color": "C0DEED",
            "profile_background_image_url": "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png",
            "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png",
            "profile_background_tile": false,
            "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/2479274491/1453298552",
            "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/748055063625605120/rByPUFsn_normal.jpg",
            "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/748055063625605120/rByPUFsn_normal.jpg",
            "profile_link_color": "0084B4",
            "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
            "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
            "profile_text_color": "333333",
            "profile_use_background_image": true,
            "protected": false,
            "screen_name": "k84362172",
            "statuses_count": 1521,
            "time_zone": null,
            "url": null,
            "utc_offset": null,
            "verified": false
        }
    }
]
```

What would be the proper command in terminal to access the last element of the json file and to see, for example, the value of attribute `"geo_enabled"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `jq` command may be your friend.

At a pinch:

```
jq .user.geo_enabled
```

It'll be a slightly longer path, given your JSON structure. Probably something like:

```
jq .[0].parent.user.geo_enabled
```

(Where 'parent' is whatever is 'above' your user key).

Comment: how to invoke jq on a file, let's say if the file is called x.json?

Comment: `jq .user.geo_enabled x.json`